# What does Yo-Kai Watch use the system clock for?

Tags: yo-kai-watch

I just started the full game for the first time, and the game warned me that messing with my 3DS system clock could mess things up in my game, because the game uses the system clock.

What does Yo-Kai Watch use the system clock for?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are 2 things that I've noticed the system clock being used for: the Crank-a-kai and Yo-kai Cam.

The Crank-a-kai disappears after you use it, but will come back the next day. If you change the system time to a day during which you've already used the Crank-a-kai, it will be unavailable.

I'm sure you've noticed in Yo-kai Cam that there is a daily challenge. For example, "Snap Bug-like Yo-kai!" or "Snap Yo-kai Rank A!" There are 64 of these challenges, each with their own reward, and they rotate on a 64-day cycle. It's possible to complete the challenge, set the system clock 64 days ahead, and complete the same challenge to get double the rewards.

There is a list of the Yo-kai Cam challenges, in order, on the [Yo-kai Watch Wiki](http://yokaiwatch.wikia.com/wiki/Yo-kai_Cam).

Answer (score 0):

The crank-a-kai restarts every day at 6 AM